# Yahoo fetching currency in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, datafeed, yahoo-finance

Does anyone know how to get a range of dates that works for fetching currency pairs from [Yahoo](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/datafeed/yahoo.html)? The code below works fine for capturing the latest rates needed? I am looking for a complete time series or matrix of the same info for a range of dates. I tried using the examples from Mathworks.com but get errors displayed below. This code works fine:

```
Connect = yahoo;
k = {'USDJPY=X' 'USDEUR=X' 'USDCAD=X' 'USDGBP=X'};
data = fetch(Connect, k)
```

where

```
USDJPY=X = USD to JPY
USDEUR=X = USD to EUR
etc...
```

If I do a range of dates, I get this error:

```
>> data = fetch(Connect, k, '24-Oct-2003',datestr(now))
Warning: Historical data fetch does not support multiple security input.
USDJPY=X data reurned. 
> In yahoo.fetch at 310
??? Error using ==> yahoo.fetch at 363
Unable to return historical data for given security.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First, if you carefully read the documentation:

> Note   Retrieving historical data for multiple securities at one time
>   is not supported for Yahoo. You can fetch historical data for only a
>   single security at a time.

So you have to specify one at a time...

As for the other part, here is an example I tried:

```
conn = yahoo;
data = fetch(conn, 'EURUSD=X', '01-Jun-2011', datestr(now,'dd-mmm-yyyy'), 'd');
close(conn)

d = [
    {'date' 'open' 'high' 'low' 'close' 'volume' 'adj-close'}
    cellstr(datestr(data(:,1))) num2cell(data(:,2:end))
];
```

I get:

```
>> d = 
    'date'          'open'   'high'   'low'    'close'    'volume'    'adj-close'
    '15-Jul-2011'   [1.41]   [1.41]   [1.41]   [ 1.41]    [     0]    [     1.41]
    '14-Jul-2011'   [1.42]   [1.42]   [1.42]   [ 1.42]    [     0]    [     1.42]
    ....
    '02-Jun-2011'   [1.45]   [1.45]   [1.45]   [ 1.45]    [     0]    [     1.45]
    '01-Jun-2011'   [1.44]   [1.44]   [1.44]   [ 1.44]    [     0]    [     1.44]
```

But for the opposite conversion `'USDEUR=X'`, you get the error:

> Unable to return historical data for given security.

By stepping through the code, the URL used to fetch the data was:

```
http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=EURUSD=X&a=5&b=1&c=2011&d=6&e=16&f=2011&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

Pasting that in your favorite browser, you will get a CSV file with the expected data. If you change it from `EURUSD` to `USDEUR` you get a 404 error: `Sorry, the page you requested was not found.`.

I'm not sure if these are the correct codes, but I tried: `JPY=X`, `CAD=X`, `EUR=X`, `GBP=X`, and they all return valid results...

As a side note: I've done a quick research, and from what I understood, the MATLAB function is using the older [Yahoo CSV API](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvHistQuotesDownload). There is a newer REST-based API for accessing the data using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) which returns XML/JSON, but I have no experience in that. There is a [YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22CADUSD%22,%22JPYUSD%22%29) you can play around with though...

HTH

---

## Update (April 2017)

I just tested the above in MATLAB R2016b, and it seems something changed in the Yahoo Finance API; It no longer returns historical currencies exchange rates **if the base is not USD**. In other words, the symbol used can only be of the form `???=X` (where `???` is the 3-letter code):

```
% US dollar to euro
data = fetch(conn, 'EUR=X', '01-Jun-2011', datestr(now,'dd-mmm-yyyy'), 'd');

% format as table
t = array2table(data, 'VariableNames',{'date' 'open' 'high' 'low' 'close' 'volume' 'adjclose'});
t.date = cellstr(datestr(t.date));
disp(t)
```

Requesting `EURUSD=X` or `USDEUR=X` only works if you don't specify a date or a date range:

```
data = fetch(conn, 'EURUSD=X')
data = fetch(conn, 'USDEUR=X')
```

To confirm, I tried using the YQL console directly with a [query](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.historicaldata+where+symbol+%3D+%22EUR%3DX%22+and+startDate+%3D+%222017-01-01%22+and+endDate+%3D+%222017-04-11%22) like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    yahoo.finance.historicaldata 
WHERE 
    symbol = "EUR=X" 
AND 
    startDate = "2017-01-01" 
AND 
    endDate = "2017-04-11"
```

with similar results. If you change the symbol to `USDEUR=X` you get "404 Not Found" errors in the results

*(BTW the YQL query uses the same CSV endpoint underneath. In case you're interested, here are [some](https://greenido.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/work-like-a-pro-with-yahoo-finance-hidden-api/) [clues](http://meumobi.github.io/stocks%20apis/2016/03/13/get-realtime-stock-quotes-yahoo-finance-api.html#historical-data) to the meaning of the parameters in the URL).*

If you're looking for the list of supported currency symbols, see this API call:

> http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote

For what it's worth, it appears that the Yahoo Finance API was never meant to be used as a public service! To quote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131228/97160):

> The reason for the lack of documentation is that **we don't have a Finance API**. It appears some have reverse engineered an API that they use to pull Finance data, but they are breaking our Terms of Service (no redistribution of Finance data) in doing this so I would encourage you to avoid using these webservices.

So no guarantees it won't break in the future...

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much. I am ok with 1 security at a time.

Comment: @heavyrockerdude: glad I could help. Consider marking it as accepted answer if you feel this has solved your problem...

Comment: In other words, historical data is not supported anymore.

Comment: @JohnAndrews partially supported (only when the base is USD)

Answer (score 0):

YQL is just using the "older" CSV API in background/as base, because YQL is a container for the CSV API. The difference is only the request type (REST or YQL). The results are the same.