# How to get json response from RESTFUL webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services, yahoo-finance

i would like to alert webservice JSON response from this url http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json&&callback=?  , how to do this,any idea?

I tried this below , but its not working at all.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var b = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json&&callback=?";
    //var b= "http://finance.yahoo.com/connection/currency-converter-cache?date=20150307";   // or this url also
    $.getJSON(b, function (e) {
    alert(e);
 });

})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0bcm6js6/)

---

**UPDATE: An Error shown on browser console**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json&&callback=?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Your fiddle is just a link to the jsfiddle homepage. As for your Yahoo link, it is returing JSON. The only bug I can see in your code is possibly the `$.getJSON` function might not work with JSONP, but I would have to look more into that

Comment: I don't think you'd have any luck as yahoo doesn't seem to support `JSONP`

Comment: @JasonSperske i have updated my question. any tips to get json response please

Comment: It means you can't request finance.yahoo.com from any other origin. Once solution might be going through yql it solves cross-orgin problem or you can give try from server side request.

Comment: A common way around this is to make the web request in your server-side code so that it is not script, and therefore not constrained by the same origin policy. Then, you expose that as a service that you can call from script because it is in your own domain.

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon But the same way this site is using & its getting result, what is the magic behind this could not able to know, any help ?  THis website: view-source:http://currency.fullstacks.net/     (tips: search "yahoo" in view source page, You can use javascript beautifier to view code http://jsbeautifier.org/  )

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way to access the Yahoo API with JSONP over YQL but I think it's better to use some other service.

It seems that Yahoo isn't supporting that API. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108399/yahoo-finance-all-currencies-quote-api-documentation).

I searched for an exchange rate json api at google and I've found [fixer.io](http://fixer.io/) which is working. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jug52ngg/) and below.

---

**Update 14.03.2015 21:09 (UTC)**

Please have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/18kk18tj/) it's a demo to access the Yahoo API. I had to add the env to all databases to be able to access the news feed for the demo. You probably can change the YQL to access the data you want.

The YQL console is very helpful to see what data are available. You can access the console [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console).

The code is from this [page](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/). The initial code was not working because it couldn't find the `search.news` table. Probably because of the env property but I need to check that.

```js
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.fixer.io/latest",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        success: function(response) {
            $(".json").text(JSON.stringify(response, null,2));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="json"></pre>
```